# .htaccess file only inside a sub folder and not the root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website which i'm currently updating. I've copied all the libraries, resources, configs etc to a folder **newsite**. As i've not implemented any url rewriting the the root old site, I want to implement it in the updating site. Therefore I've added .htaccess file inside the newsite folder. Below is the folder structure.

```
root/
|-- config/
|-- libraries/
|-- resources/
|-- newsite/
|     |-- config/
|     |-- libraries/
|     |-- resources/
|     |-- index.php
|     |-- .htaccess
|-- index.php
|-- login.php
|-- services.php
|-- contact.php
```

I want the old site to function the way it is now, but I want to implement url rewriting to the new site.

Basically the url's for the new site will be:

```
https://exmple.com/newsite/
https://exmple.com/newsite/services
https://exmple.com/newsite/login
https://exmple.com/newsite/contact
```

or any other url's. Below is the Rewrite Rule that i've written.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/newsite
RewriteRule ^newsite/(.+)$ /newsite/index.php?page_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: /newsite/ is discarded for the root/newsite/.htaccess, so this rule make sense only for root/.htaccess. Also remove redundant `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the following should work

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all requests that do not begin with /public/ or /root/ to URL that does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. In your case you are ignoring the folder. But if the folder is there in the url then it should rewrite the url.

Comment: create one routing page and all url is routing after add . htaccess file in root folder like ` root/.htaccess`